# querying id's according to an id's array

Tags: mysql, sql, database, denormalized

my website includes a mysql db with two tables.
one table has a field called 'id_array', and it contains a string look like this:
'1,3,7,78,89,102'. it represents an array of id's in the second table.

what is the best strategy for retrieving the id's in the second table?
i want the fastest way.

currently i am using 'SELECT * FROM first_table WHERE id IN (id_array)'.

i used to query one by one, but i assume it is a lot slower.

if someone has a better structure to offer me for the db, that would be great.
this structure is the best i came up with, but i'm pretty sure it is not so efficiant.
i need a fast and convenient way to find all the id's that belong to the id from the first table.

help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comma separated value means the data is denormalized -- the `IN` clause won't work for you, because it works on distinct values.

## Short Term Solution

Use [MySQL's FIND_IN_SET function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM first_table 
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, id_array)
```

## Long Term Solution

...is not to store values in this manner, which means having a table to store the distinct values and a table to join that table of distinct values to the original table. IE:

### FIRST_TABLE

- first_table_id (primary key)

### FIRST_TABLE_TYPE_CODES

- type_code_id (primary key)

### FIRST_TABLE_TYPE_MAP

- first_table_id (primary key)
- type_code_id (primary key)

Comment: first of all, it is possible that i didn't explain myself properly, sice the IN clause do work for me.

Comment: the id's in the array are the primary key's for the second table. what do you mean type code? the id's of the second table are just integers, which are auto incremented.

Comment: @Tal: I made assumptions, being there wasn't much to go on & it wasn't clear to me.  That's great if you don't need the second table -- the MAP table is what most miss regarding a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: great to hear that. so you are saying my solution is sufficient? these queries are not too slow?

Comment: @Tal: Testing is the only way to know, but I wouldn't store comma delimited data unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: i think i understand now what you meant in the long term solution. you confused me with the names for the tables you offered. i will try this solution. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a field that holds the ids that the record is related to in another table? You might want to create a lookup table that links the two tables together to help you with a many to many relationship. Post a little bit more or your db setup

Comment: thats sounds good. can you explain this concept for me? the setup is just the way you described it, one table holds string with id's from another table.

Comment: You will have 3 tables, if I have a person table with a listing of people and I want to relate them to colleges they attended. I would have the person table with a person_id and a college table with a college_id to denote unique values, the third table would have two columns, one being college_id and the other person_id (lookup table). This way one person could attend many colleges or schools. Perhaps college wasn't the best example, but hopefully you get the idea.